# What is the best practice when implementing equals() for entities with generated ids

Tags: java, hibernate

If I have a table with columns A, B, C, D
  
 A: auto-generated id (PK)
  
 B & C: combination must be unique (these are the columns that actually define identity in the business sense)
  
 D: some other columns

Now, if I'll create business objects based on this table (e.g. in Java), which one would be a better implementation of the equals() method:

1. define equality based on A
2. define equality based on B and C

or, it wouldn't really matter which of the two I choose.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Definitely B and C, because you want the `equals()` contract to be valid even before entities are persisted. You say yourself:

> these are the columns that actually
>   define identity in the business sense

If that is the case, then that is the logic `equals()` should use. Database keys are the database's concern and should be of no concern to your business layer.

And don't forget to use the same properties in `hashcode()`, too.

Comment: why exclude `A` in the `equals()` method?

Comment: Because from a business perspective, a persisted entity and a non-persisted entity with equal properties B and C are equal. The business perspective should not care about implementation details like DB id, that's relevant for the model only.

Comment: thanks. i think i'm thinking backwards (putting implementation first; business sense second). your answer made me realize that. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @S.P.Floyd as well. But I wanted to add something more.

There are situations when an entity doesn't have unique business properties. For instance, an entity may only have `A` (the PK) and `B` (a business property), but many entities have the same `B` value.

In this case, it is difficult to create an `equals()` and `hashcode()`. You certainly do not want to base them on `A`, as you won't be able to compare a persisted object with one that hasn't been persisted yet. And you can't base it on `B` alone, because then many objects that are different unique entities would appear to be the same.

What I do in these situations is have a `Date created = new Date();` property. When an entity is created, it automatically gets a created timestamp. In my `equals()` and `hashcode()` I include both `B` and `created`. This isn't perfect, as there is a very slim chance that two objects could be created at the same time (especially in a clustered solution), but it's a start. If you must, add a UID or other generated business property that isn't the database's PK.

Comment: Does the created field map to the DB or is it just an artificial (transient) field? I'd rather not like to pollute my DB tables just because I'm using a specific technology, here JPA.

Comment: @Kawu - in my case, the `created` field does map to the database, but I need that information anyway. It would be much harder to make a transient field work as it would be more likely for dates to collide when pulling a collection of objects from the DB. I consider the created date to be when the DB entity was originally created, not the date the object was pulled from your database and turned into a pojo again.

Answer (score 2):

If (B,C) is a unique pair, there's no need for an auto-generated id in addition. For the table, A is equivalent to (B,C) (one-to-one relation).

You may want or need the extra key, but I agree with seanizer, use (B,C) for equals and because A is redundant (and `null` before the object is persisted), don't use that for equals (and hashcode)

Comment: But Hibernate recommends surrogate key, and natural keys should be marked `@NaturalId`.