# Problem with equals() method in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am developing an application in Hibernate where I have model classes like these:

```
public class Employee
{
    private int ID;
    private String name;
    private Department department;
    //other properties
    //constructors, getters and setters
}
```

Note that the `ID` is not a value populated by the user and is populated using `GenerationType.Identity` as the `strategy`.

Also I have another class `Department` as follows:

```
public class Department
{
    private int ID;
    private String name;

    private Set<Employee> employees; //this is actually a HashSet

    //other implementations
}
```

There is a `ManyToOne` bi-directional relationship between an `Employee` and a `Department`.

So to add a new `Employee` to an existing `Department`, I do the following

```
Department existingDepartment = ...;
Employee newEmployee = ...;

existingDepartment.addEmployee(newEmployee);
employee.setDepartent(existinDepartment);

session.save(newEmployee);
```

Now conceptually two `Employee` objects are the same if they have the same `ID`. So my `equals()` method in the `Employee` class looks like this:

```
public boolean equals(Object o)
{
    if(!(o instanceOf Employee))
    {
        return false;
    }

    Employee other = (Employee)o;

    if(this.ID == o.etID())
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Now the problem is when I create a `new Employee();` I do not have its `ID`, since it will be assigned when it will be persisted. So when I say

```
existingDepartment.addEmployee(newEmployee);
```

the internal `HashSet` of the `Department` object is effectively using an `equals()` method which is broken [since it uses a member variable to determine equality that as not been initialized properly].

This seems like a very basic problem but, how do I solve it? Or am I designing my classes totally wrong? Or should my `equals` method be re-written to compare other values instead of `ID`, which I guess would be absurd.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> This seems like a very basic problem but, how do I solve it? Or am I
>   designing my classes totally wrong? Or should my equals method be
>   re-written to compare other values instead of ID, which I guess would
>   be absurd.

There are two different philosophies concerning this.

a) equals() / hashCode() based on DB id

Drawback: you can't compare persistent and non-persistent objects

b) equals() / hashCode() based on contents

Drawback: two objects with the same id may turn out to be non-equal.

I prefer the second approach, it makes more sense from a Java point of view (although admittedly not from a DB point of view). **The only thing I'd want to make sure is that you never mix the approaches.**

This has been discussed many times before, btw:

> - [Should I write equals() methods in JPA entities?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4388360/342852)
> - [What is the best practice when implementing equals() for entities with generated ids](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4323245/342852)
> - [JPA : not overriding equals() and hashCode() in the entities?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5191406/342852)
>     (etc.)

Comment: +1 with a note that the second approach is the only way to do it that won't break hashing collections by mutating a property of a contained object upon which equals() and hashCode() are dependent.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your equals method, so that it returns false, when `o` is null:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final Employee other = (Employee) obj;
    if (this.id != other.id && (this.id == null || !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: My `ID`s are `int`s, primitives. :-)

Comment: "My IDs are ints, primitives." That's usually a very bad idea.

Comment: @Sean, you shouldn't use boxed primitives unless you have to. This might be a good case to use them but if you use all boxed ints all the time then that's horrible practice and you lose a lot of performance too.

Comment: @Amir in general, I agree (especially when you are doing arithmetics, of course). But for persistent entities, wrappers are the easiest way to distinguish between set and unset IDs.

Comment: Agreed on explaining why and where to use wrappers.

Comment: oops. kind of eluded me that you're using int primitives :) sry

Answer (score 0):

In hibernate usually you can tell it to use a value when it hasn't been saved to db. For example, I have used `-1` for an ID which hasn't been stored yet.

You should initialize your ids like this to make sure you get a consistent behavior.

```
private int ID = -1;
```

Comment: you are referring to the `unsaved-value` attribute http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id

Answer (score 0):

You may add an transient field with an different non-persistent id. (maybe you should upgrade to "long" id).
Something like this for Example

```
public class Employee {
  private static int lastTID = 0;
  private int ID = -1;
  private transient int tID;
 ..
 public Employee () {
    synchronized (getClass()) {
      tId = -- lastTID;
    }
 }
 public boolean equals(Object o) {
 ..
   Employee other = (Employee)o;
 ..
   if (ID != -1) {
    return ID == other.ID;
   } else {
    return other.ID == -1 && tID == other.tID;
   }
 }
```

In any case you have to assure that there are not saved and unsaved Employee in use.

Another strategy is to save Employee first and then to add it to Department