# Spring Data JPA: How to set 2 foreign keys on the child entity during insert

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, foreign-keys

I am new to Spring JPA and I am having some trouble with setting foreign keys on an entity when inserting a row.

I have the following entities

```java
@Entity
public class Department {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private String departmentName;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "department_id")
    List<Employee> employees;
}
```

```java
@Entity
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private String employeeName;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")
    List<Role> roles;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "department_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Department department;
}
```

```java
@Entity
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private String roleName;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Employee employee;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "department_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Department department;
}
```

And here is the Department Repository:

```java
@Repository
public interface DepartmentRepository extends JpaRepository<Department, Integer> {

    Department findById(long id);

}
```

With this approach, the `department_id` in the `employee` table and the `employee_id` in the `role` table is set correctly when I save a `Department` object using `departmentRepository.save(department)`.

But I also want it to set the `department_id` in the `role` table. How can this be achieved? Currently the relationship Department and Role is indirect (i.e it is through Employee) but would I have to create a direct relationship between the 2 entities? I am not sure how to achieve this though. Any input will be appreciated.

Edit:

I want to model the relationship in this [Entity Relationship diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooDoy.png)

Answer (score 0):

As I see that you already using

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
```

So you knew that every update on Department with list Employee can do "many" things.

So Employee do the same to Roles (your list) but the magic auto save/update won't help.

Condition now:

- Save action in repo
- List of Employee
- List of Role in employee (each object don't have Department Id)

As I understand:

You have Department that 1-n to Employee (Employee can only have 1 Department)

Employee can have many Role

As normal logic: Deparment 1-n Employee 1-n Roles

> But some how you want Role have object of Department also.

So my first suggestion is change of logic code.

And second: a way to solve your problem!

#### Create Department

when add Role to Employee, please access and add deparment_id also.
(Department save List Employee, when save Employee - list Roles also save with same logic, just make sure to add it)

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-cascade-types

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41344032/how-to-cascade-create-and-store-references-in-the-same-spring-data-jpa-save-requ