# Hibernate 3 to 4 migration

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

After migrating from Hibernate 3 to 4 I am seeing below warnings in my server logs :

composite-id class does not override equals() composite-id class does not override hashcode()

Also I am getting SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException(Not always)

My CompositeKeyClass does not override equals() and hashcode().But I am not facing any issues with Hibernate3.

Please help me understand if the equals() and hashcode() override is required only from Hibernate 4?

Comment: It's almost always necessary to override eq/hc for correct work of any Hibernate version.  Since version 4, hibernate  became more verbose and does more validations. 

Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388360/should-i-write-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-jpa-entities

Answer (score 0):

The warnings are now gone after overriding equals and hc methods.
The Integrity constraint violation was not due to this.It was due to a wrong configuration in my data source.